# RuntimeException, ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCount$Map not found . Mapper class issue

Tags: java, mapreduce, classnotfoundexception, hortonworks-data-platform, word-count

I am trying to run WordCount on sandBox HortonWork HDP. I  have searched this error in many places and applied what they said and I could not make it run.

Step by Step:
1- First I compile the java program

```
javac -cp .:$(hadoop classpath) WordCount.java
```

2- Next bundle the classes as a jar file

```
jar cvf WordCount.jar *.class
```

3- Lets look at the content of the jar file:

```
jar tf WordCount.jar

META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WordCount.class
WordCount$Map.class
WordCount$Reduce.class
```

4- Next set the input file into hdfs and run the job.

```
hdfs dfs -put file.txt

hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount /user/root/file.txt /user/root/output
```

5- And I got the following error :

```
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
16/08/12 04:02:49 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
16/08/12 04:02:49 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15:8050
16/08/12 04:02:50 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
16/08/12 04:02:50 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/08/12 04:02:51 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/08/12 04:02:51 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1470929339157_0022
16/08/12 04:02:51 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
16/08/12 04:02:51 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1470929339157_0022
16/08/12 04:02:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8088/proxy/application_1470929339157_0022/
16/08/12 04:02:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1470929339157_0022
16/08/12 04:03:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1470929339157_0022 running in uber mode : false
16/08/12 04:03:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/08/12 04:03:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/08/12 04:03:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1470929339157_0022_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCount$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCount$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    ... 8 more

16/08/12 04:03:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/08/12 04:03:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1470929339157_0022_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCount$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCount$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    ... 8 more

16/08/12 04:03:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1470929339157_0022_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCount$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class WordCount$Map not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    ... 8 more

16/08/12 04:03:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/08/12 04:03:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1470929339157_0022 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1470929339157_0022_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

16/08/12 04:03:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 13
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=4
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=4
        Other local map tasks=3
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=20865
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=20865
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=0
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=20865
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=5216250
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
```

`

And the following code is the one I try to run:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    int res = ToolRunner.run(new WordCount(), args);
    System.exit(res);
  }

  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
    Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

    Configuration conf = getConf();
    Job job = new Job(conf, this.getClass().toString());
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPath);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);

    job.setJobName("WordCount");
    //job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    //FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPath);
    //FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);

   return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
  }

  public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                    Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String line = value.toString();
      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
      while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable value : values) {
        sum += value.get();
      }

      context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help/hint and advice.

Comment: No need to mark posts as Solved. That's what the checkmark next to the answer means

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction. Best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding following in your class

```
job.setJar("WordCount.jar");
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I remember I have tried this one too - may be for some other -version:)

Comment: Could you tell me if  you have any idea why this made it to run?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

run mapreduce jar like this:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/path/to/the/jar/examples.jar; 
hadoop jar /path/to/the/jar/examples.jar WordCount /data/tmp/input1.txt /data/tmp/output2
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant and non error prone solution is to use the following:

```
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
```

Make sure also you're calling the following too to avoid stop of your program:

```
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```